# Find linear map of a transformation without neither known transformed or transformation mitrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider the linear map from $R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ which takes $\vec{e_1}$ to $\vec{a_1}=\begin{bmatrix} 1\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}$, takes $\vec{e_2}$ to $\vec{a_2}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\3\end{bmatrix}$, and takes $\vec{e_3}$ to $\vec{a_3}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\5\\1\end{bmatrix}$. What is the matrix of this linear map?

Here is how I am approaching this question:

From what is given I know that:

$$
\vec{e_1} \times \vec{x} = \vec{a_1}\\
\vec{e_2} \times \vec{x} = \vec{a_2}\\
\vec{e_3} \times \vec{x} = \vec{a_3}\\
$$

Then I will end up with 3 equations per each (total of 9 equations). But I do now know where should I go from there? Should I use row echelon form to find the result? How  should I deal with 9 equations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that the matrix of this linear map is:
$$
M = \begin{bmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13} \\
m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23} \\
m_{31} & m_{32} & m_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then since $M\vec{e_1} = \vec{a_1}$, we know that:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{11} \\ m_{21} \\ m_{31}
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
m_{11} & m_{12} & m_{13} \\
m_{21} & m_{22} & m_{23} \\
m_{31} & m_{32} & m_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Continuing in this manner, we conclude that:
$$
M = [\vec{a_1} ~|~ \vec{a_2} ~|~ \vec{a_3}] = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 1 & 5 \\
-1 & 3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$